# Cache-Control: I don't understand `must-understand`

Tags: http, cache-control

I don't understand the `must-understand` directive of the HTTP `Cache-Control` header. **What are some examples of when this would be used, and what sort of status code might a server use that a cache may or may not understand?**

[Documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#must-understand):

> The `must-understand` response directive indicates that a cache should store the response only if it understands the requirements for caching based on status code.
>
> `must-understand` should be coupled with `no-store` for fallback behavior.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: must-understand, no-store
> ```
>
> If a cache doesn't support `must-understand`, it will be ignored. If `no-store` is also present, the response isn't stored.
>
> If a cache supports `must-understand`, it stores the response with an understanding of cache requirements based on its status code.

It is also formally described in [RFC 9111](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9111#name-must-understand):

> The must-understand response directive limits caching of the response to a cache that understands and conforms to the requirements for that response's status code.
>
> A response that contains the must-understand directive **SHOULD** also contain the no-store directive. When a cache that implements the must-understand directive receives a response that includes it, the cache **SHOULD** ignore the no-store directive if it understands and implements the status code's caching requirements.

Despite these descriptions, I still have no idea in what situations this directive would be useful.

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-16.2.2-6 seems relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that lead to the introduction of the `must-understand` directive can be found [at github](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120). The status quo was that any final (non-1XX) status could be cached, and a cache implementation would cache any response with a status defined as *cacheable by default* or sent with a caching header. However, some statuses do require some extra handling (most notably 206 and 304), some statuses should never be cached (like 421 or 502).

Mark Nottingham [wrote](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120#issuecomment-402888799) ([2](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120#issuecomment-448058828))

> […] deployed implementations do cache responses with explicit freshness, even without understanding the status code.

> The problem that we're trying to solve here is that many caches have a long deployment cycle, and having them align their behaviour upon a list of specified status codes rather than an in-protocol signal isn't great.
>
> […] a new status code with operation similar to `206 Partial Content` would be cached incorrectly if the cache directives in it don't apply to the response it occurs within.
>
> In the (unlikely) even that we want to introduce a new partial-like response status in the future, we just need to have those responses include this [proposed `must-understand`] cache-control directive to explicitly mark that response as different.

So they introduced this solely for forward-compatibility purposes, to handle the [definition of new status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-16.2.2-6). There no longer is (or will never be) a [list of exceptions](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2009OctDec/0221.html), instead the old behaviour is enshrined explicitly:

> The definition of a new final status code ought to specify whether or not it is *heuristically cacheable* [previously: *cacheable by default*]. Note that any response with a final status code can be cached if the response has explicit freshness information. A status code defined as *heuristically cacheable* is allowed to be cached without explicit freshness information. Likewise, the definition of a status code can place constraints upon cache behavior if the must-understand cache directive is used.

I cannot give an example of such a new status code. The hope is that they never will exist and define exotic caching requirements. To quote Mark Nottingham again:

> My reaction to that is that we shouldn't be designing new mechanisms like partial content that mess with the HTTP so deeply; I hope we've learned by now that they don't work well.

But you never know. Also, the existence of this directive alone allows cache implementations to decide that they will cache responses with status codes unknown to them, without fear of breaking in the future. This eases the introduction of new status codes, with normal caching semantics, and ensures that they will get cached properly right from the beginning without having to update the web infrastructure.

Answer (score 6):

Found a good explanation of the rationales for the `must-understand` directive, including use cases, [here](https://blog.jxck.io/entries/2021-02-12/cache-control-must-understand.html) (it is in Japanese, so you might need a [translator](https://blog-jxck-io.translate.goog/entries/2021-02-12/cache-control-must-understand.html?_x_tr_sl=ja&_x_tr_tl=en)). At the end of that page, there is a reference to the [ticket/discussion of the HTTP Working Group re: `must-understand`](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120).

To summarize both:

- (Old) RFC 7234 [conflicts with itself](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120#issuecomment-448058828) in the caching behavior for **new** http status codes:

  - On the one hand, it says (a) "The definition of a **new** status code ought to specify whether or not it is cacheable."
  - On the other hand, it says (b) "**all** status codes can be cached if the response they occur in has explicit freshness information"
- For the new RFC 9111, [the editors wanted to clarify the behaviour for new status codes](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120#issuecomment-448058828), without having to wait for the final specification of these new status codes and their cache behaviour, because cache implementations have long deployment cycles.
- [So they kept (b) above, but introduced a new limitation and mechanism for (a) that works regardless of specification status](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120#issuecomment-508625404):

  - If a response carries `Cache-Control: must-understand`, a cache MUST NOT store a response unless it understands and implements the relevant semantics of the status code.

How that changes things when new status codes are introduced:

- Before: [new / not specified status codes unknown to implementations **sometimes get cached, and sometimes they don't**](https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/120#issuecomment-402888799)
- Now: By providing `Cache-Control: must-understand`, servers can explicitly specify that responses should **only be cached if the cache supports the semantics of the status code**.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In the meantime I researched this out of curiosity, and wrote an answer myself. Gladly it doesn't disagree with what you found :-)